# Specify which fields are indexed in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with a number of fields that I never query on so I would like to turn indexing on those fields off to save resources. I believe I need to [disable the `_all` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/all-field.html), but how do I specify which fields are indexed then?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default all the fields are indexed within the [_all](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/all-field.html) special field as well, which provides the so called catchall feature out of the box. However, you can specify for each field in your mapping whether you want to add it to the _all field or not, through the `include_in_all` option:

```
"person" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "include_in_all" : false
        }
    }
}
```

The above example disables the default behaviour for the name field, which won't be part of the _all field.

Otherwise, if you don't need the _all field at all for a specific type you can disable it like this, again in your mapping:

```
"person" : {
    "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "string", "store" : "yes"
        }
    }
}
```

When you disable it your fields will still be indexed separately, but you won't have the catchall feature that _all provides. You will need then to query your specific fields instead of relying on the _all special field, that's it. In fact, when you query and don't specify a field, elasticsearch queries the _all field under the hood, unless you override the default field to query.

Comment: Thanks for that! So I can just disable `_all` since I'm not using that feature and hopefully that should reduce the size of the index. And, if I understood well, the only other option to reduce the index size I have is to specify `not_analyzed` on the fields I don't search on?

Comment: Well, that's not just to change the index size...it changes how data is indexed. If you don't analyze a field it will contain a single token. No tokenizers nor token filters will be used. If it contains a sentence (with whitespaces etc.), in order to have a match on it you need to query for the whole exact sentence. If you never query a field just set indexed=false.

Comment: Yep that's what I thought. Thanks for the explanation. I have some fields in my documents like 'description' or 'links' that I never need to search on so it's a waste of resources to analyze them. And I'm testing out running the whole index in memory (`{"index" : { "store.type" : "memory"}}`) so index size will become an important factor.

Comment: This still creates index for each individual fields,Use "dynamic": "false" to create specific indexes.Check my answer

Answer (score 16):

Each string field has `index` param in the mapping config, which [defaults to](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string) `analyzed`. That means that besides the _all field each field is indexed solely.

And for the [_all field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) it is said in reference that:

> By default, it is enabled and all fields are included in it for ease of use.

So, to completely disable indexing for a field you have to specify (if the _all field is enabled):

```
    "mappings": {
        "your_mapping": {
            "properties": {
                "field_not_to_index": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "include_in_all": false,
                    "index": "no"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For the fields that should be queried on whether include them in the _all field (with `"index": "no"` to save resources) if you query through the _all field, or if you query on those fields solely use the `index` param with any positive value (`analyzed` or `not_analyzed`) and disable the _all field to save resources.

Answer (score 3):

Following is an important doc page to understand the index settings in elastic search
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html

For your problem, ideally you should set the "index" flag to no in the field properties.

Comment: In that link, the example shows "index": "not_analyzed". But I thought indexing and analyzing are distinct concepts in ES? Is 'no' a different setting than 'not_analyzed'? Please clarify.

Comment: `analyzed`
    First analyze the string and then index it. In other words, index this field as full text. 
`not_analyzed`
    Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as specified. Do not analyze it. 
`no`
    Don’t index this field at all. This field will not be searchable.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize `enabled` field to disable particular field or entire mapping.
[ElasticSearch Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/enabled.html)

Disable Field mapping (i.e. `session_data` field)

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "session_data": { 
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Disable entire mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": { 
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

_all has been deprecated since 6.0. Use below

```
"mappings": {
    "dynamic":"false",
    "properties": {
    "field_to_index":{"index": true, "type": "text"}
  }
```

According to es docs

Setting dynamic to false doesn’t alter the contents of the _source field at all. The _source will still contain the whole JSON document that you indexed. However, any unknown fields will not be added to the mapping and will not be searchable.

Answer (score 1):

Set dynamic index and _all index to false. Specify the required fields in mapping.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "candidates":{
         "_all":{
            "enabled":false
         },
          "dynamic": "false", 
         "properties":{
            "tags":{
               "type":"text"
            },
            "derivedAttributes":{
               "properties":{
                "city":{
                     "type":"text"
                  },
                  "zip5":{
                     "type":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```