# Exclude only 1 field from indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need your help with ElasticSearch field indexes.

I'm sending Jsons to ES and I have only 1 field that I send XML and I never search on this field.

I need your help to exclude ONLY this field from indexing. The field that I would like to exclude is: **rawXml**

Please let me know if you need more details from me.

Is this possible?

This is the Json i'm sending now :

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.05.05",
  "_type": "XXXXX",
  "_id": "XXXXXX",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": 1,
    "@timestamp": "2015-05-05T00:00:11.489Z",
    "host": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "application_name": "XXXXXXX",
    "logger_name": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "thread_name": "XXXXXXX",
    "name": "XXXXXXXX",
    "rawXml": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<XXXXX xmlns=\"http://XXXXXXXX\" Version=\"14.000\">\n    <POS>\n        <Source DKNumber=\"XXXXXX\"/>\n    </POS>\n    <Unique>\n        <ID PCC=\"XXXXX\" GDS=\"XXXXX\" NAME=\"XXXXXX\" TYPE=\"XXXXXX\"/>\n    </Unique>\n</OpenHotelHubSessionCreateRQ>\n",
    "type": "XXXXXXXX",
    "message": "Event: XXXXXXX",
    "requestContext": {
      "wml-locale": "en_AU",
      "accountId": XXXXXXX,
      "agentName": "XXXXXXX",
      "deviceType": "XXXXXX",
      "cwtTraveller": {
        "clientTopGuid": "XXXXX",
        "travellerGuid": "XXXXXXX",
        "clientTopTravelerTypeGuid": "XXXXXX",
        "clientSubGuid": "XXXXXXXX"
      },
      "providerSessionId": null,
      "variantId": X
    },
    "path": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "hostname": "XXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "sort": [
    1430784011489
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use [Bool Query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with `must_not`.

Comment: How i can use the Bool Query ? i can't add some field in logstash config file ?

Comment: Please show the JSON you have now.

Comment: It is helpful for us to know your mapping and an example of an indexed document structure/content. Could you post here?

Comment: I edited the first msg with the json including the XML

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626617/specify-which-fields-are-indexed-in-elasticsearch