# How to specify fields which should not be indexed in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I specify the fields in ElasticSearch which I *do not* want to be indexed? I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626617/specify-which-fields-are-indexed-in-elasticsearch) but I didn't understand its answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping should be something like this:

```
"index_name": {
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "unsearchable_field_name": {
            "index": "no"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that `unsearchable_field_name` still may to be stored (depends on your dynamic mapping config, take a look into [Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html)), but by setting `index: no`, Elasticsearch ignores this field on search requests.

Comment: how to do the mapping in Elasticsearch npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch module or in mongoosastic module https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic#setup .

Comment: you'll need to take a look into docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-putmapping

Comment: can u please tel me how to do that i mean can u please provide me the code to put mapping on index ''posts" and field name "jeb_no" it will be really helpful.