# How does creating an inverted index (equivalent of MongoDB's index) in elasticsearch look?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, database

I'm completely new to Elasticsearch

I know that elasticsearch's indexes are not mongobd's indexes , they are like mongodb's collections

I have some indexes in elasticsearch ( equivalent of MongoDB's collections ) and I want to make sure specific fields in them are going to be indexed (speed of retrieving them will be improved etc).

How do I do it?

In mongodb it was pretty simple since I could use createindex() and ensureindex() methods on a collection , for example :

db.collection1.createIndex({pancake_id: 1, pancakenumber: 1}, {unique: true})
db.collection1.ensureIndex({"eventbegindate": 1, "bike_id": 1})

How do I achieve the same thing in elasticsearch?

Are there any equivalents to these functions?

Thank you in advance , elasticsearch's documentation seems unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create index and type as below:

```
PUT /{index}/{type}/{id}
{
  "field": "value",
  ...
}
```

it will index documents

And disable "include_in_all" to false for index certain fields

Comment: But is indexing specific fields in a document possible?                           Like in here :                                               db.collection1.createIndex({pancake_id: 1, pancakenumber: 1}, {unique: true})                                                     db.collection1.ensureIndex({"eventbegindate": 1, "bike_id": 1})

Comment: yes it is possible. you can find your answer in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626617/specify-which-fields-are-indexed-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Thank you. So if all of the fields are indexed by default then I guess setting indexes manually is not necessery. Btw I know it's a bit offtopic but what about equivalent of mongodb's validating data? Can I validate the data that is inserted or it is also not possible sicne the db is schema free?

Comment: yes it is possible. you can validate data. for that you can use mongoose. refer this link: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html