# Elastic Search indexing/mapping on a complex typed schema

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm an ES newbie, and my first project on ES is has some complication. So coming hear asking for help.

We got a wide variability of products that different kinds of products has different set of attributes that we care about. For example,  for smart phones, we care about RAM, CPU, etc. For books, we care about author, version, etc. 
In order to put them all in one data store, the storage schema looks like this:

ProductId: Int, Attribute_Key, Attribute_Name:String, Attribute_Value: String

So for a smart phone and a book, the records can look like:

```
phoneId, 3, "CPU Speed", "2GHz"
phoneId, 4, "RAM", "2GB"
bookId, 83, "Author", "Mark Twin"
bookId, 95, "Published", "1935"
```

For now I have about 50 attribute names, that's not a lot. I want to index all of them. Unlike the normal indexing/mapping mechanism in ES, you can directly assign which "column" you want to index against. For this kind of schema, how should I tell ES to index against all the possible attribute names? Since I only have around 50 of them?

For example, I want to index against RAM, Author, Published. It looks like a multi-field indexing, but have no experience around this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: which version of elastic-search do you plan to use ?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13627218/1849366

Comment: The version of the elastic search is 2.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mapping. This will index only RAM, Author and Published.

```
"person" : {
   "properties" : {
       "CPU_Speed" : {
           "type" : "string", 
           "include_in_all" : false
        },
       "RAM" : {
           "type" : "string"
        },
       "Author" : {
           "type" : "string"
        },
       "Published" : {
           "type" : "string" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vinod, it looks like I need to add all the 40 attribute names, and it does not guard for the future attribute names. Thinking about two fields combined index makes more sense. But don't know how to do it yet....

Comment: @ShiChen i didnt get your comment "Thinking about two fields combined index makes more sense". Can you explain it briefly.