# Elastic search index on all attributes?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search

I am new to elastic search(ES) and have gone through basic tutorials like 
[this mykong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hello-world-example/)

I have question on create part of any document

CREATE Operation Example
To insert a new Document with /mkyong/posts/1001 and the following Request Data:

```
    {
      "title": "Java 8 Optional In Depth",
      "category":"Java",
      "published_date":"23-FEB-2017",
      "author":"Rambabu Posa"
    }
```

**Question 1 :-** Will ES create the inverted index on all attributes of above document i.e. `title/category/published/author` by default and provide
full text search or I need to mention it explicitly ?

**Question 2 :-** In above example we already have unique_id i.e. `1001`. That's fine if I am already storing it in DB and generate ID. What if
I need to generate the ID through ES engine and do not have any DB ?

**Update :-**

Got the answer for question 1 from [Specify which fields are indexed in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626617/specify-which-fields-are-indexed-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1 :-** Yes, by default ES will index your field twice as two separate types.  Once as "text" and once as "keyword" as a sub-field like "title.keyword".  The "text" type runs through language analyzers to support the standard search case (remove stop words, stem words, etc).  The "keyword" type makes no changes and indexes the data exactly as it is support exact match and aggregations.  You can explicitly tell ES a mapping for any field, but if you don't this is the default behavior.

Here is some information on the text vs keyword behavior:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

**Question 2 :-** ES will automatically create it's own internal ID for every document you index in a field called "_id".  You can technically replace this with your own ID, but typically you don't want to do that because it can impact performance by making ES's hashing algorithm to spread out the data preform poorly.  It is usually better to just to add any ID's you would like as new fields in the document and let ES index them for you, ideally as the keyword type.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

Comment: Two follow up questions. My main question was will elastic search create the full text search on all columns(`title/category/published/author` in my case) of document  or I need to mention which specific column of document i need to create index? Now coming back to your answers. 

`Answer 1:-` Do you mean keyword search will work in same fashion as something `like` keyword in sql db where `text` will work as full ntext search ?

Comment: `Answer 2:-`  Also I did not get how using _id created by ES can impact the performance ? Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: Answer 1: Yes, the text type supports full text search and the keyword type is an exact match like a typical SQL DB would support.

Comment: Answer 2: The _id of the document is used with a hashing function to determine what shard (which implies which machines) to put the document on.  The _id's generated by ES are guaranteed to be balanced when used with this hashing function.  If you generate your own that may not be the case and you may end up with more data in some shards than others.