# Fields that need not be searchable in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch v6 to search my product catalog.

My product has a number fields, such as title, description, price, etc... one of the fields is: photo_path, which would contain the location of product photo on disk.

photo_path does need to be searched, but need to be retrieved.

**Question**: Is there a way to mark this field as not searchable/not indexed? And is this a good idea, for example will I save storage/process time, by marking this field not searchable.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626617/specify-which-fields-are-indexed-in-elasticsearch) and read, [_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) and [_all](http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html), but since _all is deprecated in version 6, I am confused what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify which fields are indexed in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626617/specify-which-fields-are-indexed-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Thanks @Waqas, questions are the same, but the reason I asked it again is that _all field is depricated in version 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some field are not indexed are not queryable, setting property`"index": false`, and if you only want "photo_path" field as the search result, includes this field on source only (save disk space and fetch less data from disk), show mappings like below:

```
{
"mappings": {
    "data": {
        "_source": {
            "includes": [
                "photo_path" // search result only contains this
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "photo_path": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "doc_values": false,  // Set docValues as false if you don't want to use this field to sort/aggregate
                "index": false   // Not index this field
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}